# Keymaps for pie menu addon not being added regardless of method used

Tags: python, add-on, keymap

Blender Version: 3.6.5 from Steam
i'm currently working on an add-on for a pie menu, currently none of the methods i could find online nor my own mixes of those seems to work

- keymaps are not being added
- there is no error in the console
- refreshing addons does nothing to the keymaps

this is a variation of the same method i was using in a previous version but due to a blender bug a lot of duplicates were generated and i needed to reset keymaps preference, now it has stopped working completely

The Code here is almost a full copy of an answer on another post, i tried methods from blender's built-in addons none of those work either

**Note:** sometimes(rarely) it does add a keymap but it's gone after restart, and trying to to save preferences stops the addon from being enabled

The code works, the keybind doesn't: [YT Video](https://youtu.be/O0cBtfX0GUU)

Full Code Here in case it's coming from something unrelated to the keymaps code: [Github](https://github.com/Valery-AA/AlxOverHaul)

```
addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    for AlxQCls in AlxClassQueue:
        bpy.utils.register_class(AlxQCls)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon

    km = kc.keymaps.new(name='3D View')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(idname="wm.call_menu_pie", type="A", value="CLICK", ctrl=True, shift=False, alt=True, head=True)
    kmi.properties.name = Alx_MT_AlexandriaToolPie.bl_idname

    addon_keymaps.append((km,kmi))

    print("AlxRegister Called")
    print("ALX_LIBRARY_LOADED")
    print(AlxClassQueue)
```

Comment: I think `value` should be `'PRESS'` with keyboard keys, not sure if that might be the cause of the problem though.

Comment: i originally thought that too but it doesn't work regardless of the value type it was originally "PRESS" and that too fails, the thing that i'm currently looking into is that the issue might lie in how pie menu keybinds are assigned, as other non pie menu keys seem to work more consistently, either **wm.call_menu_pie** is the issue or **property.name** as when those are not present an empty keybind is added succesfully

Comment: I think it might be elsewhere in the code then.

Comment: the pie menu can actually be called and works correctly, it was originally a panel that got adapted to a pie menu, things like custom buttons and the search menu allow it to open with no issues, but any keybind added in the addon works even for pie menus but adding wm.call_menu_pie with a property.name adds no keymap even for existing pie menus, i tried "hijacking" both bagapie and machin3tools bl_idname  and still doesn't work

Comment: The code doesn't run. You put everything in needlessly many functions and call them before they are defined and also try to use variables that are not yet defined. The order in which you write code matters. Why not just add all the classes to a list and register them in register function in a loop? I think you should put the handler in register/unregister functions as well.  I think it's also not that usual to have match-case statement for only 2 cases based on boolean value - that should just be an if statement.

Comment: this is my bad, the release is the "stable" version and is old about a month i tend to wait before actually updating the release to make it stable but even the direct code is not the latest, those are redundant functions indeed, i was using them to get clear errors, matches are only boolean now it's a 0.3.1, it's in its bare minimum state with only built in options at the moment, and when it comes to the loop on a list to register them, am i not doing it? haven't coded with python in half a decade idk about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr properties.name should respect alx_name_here for ui and alx.name_here for operators

The issue with this was the documentation all along, nowhere there is the mention that properties.name when assigning a menu to wm.call_pie_menu the item  bl_idname need to follow that standard, which in this case the . present in the panel was not reported with an error

the previously mentioned reason was a missguiding due to internal blender naming conventions have class name identical to bl_idnames

12/02/2024

semi working function for keymaps with which i resolved the issue:

```
def AlxKeymapRegister(KeymapCallType="", SpaceType="EMPTY", RegionType="WINDOW", ItemidName="", Key="", KeyModifier="", UseShift=False, UseCtrl=False, UseAlt=False, TriggerType="PRESS"):
    """
    Keymap Call Type: [OPERATOR, MENU, PANEL, PIE]
    Region Type: [WINDOW]
    """
    if (ItemidName != ""):
        WindowManager = bpy.context.window_manager
        KeyConfigs = WindowManager.keyconfigs.addon

        if KeyConfigs:

            CallType = ""
            if (KeymapCallType == "OPERATOR"):
                CallType = ItemidName
            if (KeymapCallType == "MENU"):
                CallType = "wm.call_menu"
            if (KeymapCallType == "PANEL"):
                CallType = "wm.call_panel"
            if (KeymapCallType == "PIE"):
                CallType = "wm.call_menu_pie"

            KeymapName = ""
            if (RegionType == "WINDOW") and (SpaceType != "VIEW_3D"):
                KeymapName = "Window"
                SpaceType = "EMPTY"
            if (SpaceType == "VIEW_3D"):
                KeymapName = "3D View"
            
            if (KeyModifier == ""):
                KeyModifier = "NONE"

            if (CallType != "") and (SpaceType != ""):
                Keymap = KeyConfigs.keymaps.new(name=KeymapName, space_type=SpaceType, region_type=RegionType)
                KeymapItem = Keymap.keymap_items.new(CallType, type=Key, key_modifier=KeyModifier, shift=UseShift, ctrl=UseCtrl, alt=UseAlt, value=TriggerType, head=True)
                if (KeymapCallType in ["PANEL", "PIE"]):
                    KeymapItem.properties.name = ItemidName
                AlxAddonKeymaps.append((Keymap, KeymapItem))
```